# How to configure nginx in order to cross-origin

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx

In my local development environment,i used 'proxy' to solve the problem with cross-origin,The database can accept data

```
    "/api": {
    "target": "http://ip:8889/api",
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "pathRewrite": { "^/api" : "" }
  } //proxy configuration file
```

but when i put them on the website(linux,nginx),something is wrong，The database can not accept data

nginx configuration file

```
server {
        listen 8000;
        server_name _;

        root /home/myftp/dist;
        index index.html index.htm;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
        location ^~ /assets/ {
                gzip_static on;
                expires max;
                add_header Cache-Control public;
        }
location /api {
    rewrite  ^.+api/?(.*)$ /$1 break;
    include  uwsgi_params;
       proxy_pass   http://localhost:8889;
       }
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
        client_max_body_size 20M;
        keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

The console prompt 404 not found ,but The results of the local otest are all ok ，I already check my nginx success.log,error.log,there is no logs which from my ip:8000

could some help me with this~ thanks :)

Comment: Is port 8000 open on the firewall?

Comment: @DanNagle all the port is opening include 8000,8889,the question is solved.
i should put the 'location /api'  in the front ,beacuse the rules of nginx are matched from top to toe :)